# Creating a 'differences' result set of two pandas dataframes with grouped key columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'll try to keep this this short and to the point (with simplified data). I have a table of data that has four columns (keep in mind more columns may be added later), none of which are unique on their own, but these three columns together 'ID','ID2','DO' must be unique as a group. I will bring this table into one dataframe, and the updated version of the table into another dataframe.

If df is the 'original data' and df2 is the 'updated data', is this the most accurate/efficient way to find what changes occur to the original data?

```
import pandas as pd
#Sample Data:
df  = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[546,107,478,546,478], 'ID2':['AUSER','BUSER','CUSER','AUSER','EUSER'], 'DO':[3,6,8,4,6], 'DATA':['ORIG','ORIG','ORIG','ORIG','ORIG']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[107,546,123,546,123], 'ID2':['BUSER','AUSER','DUSER','AUSER','FUSER'], 'DO':[6,3,2,4,3], 'DATA':['CHANGE','CHANGE','CHANGE','ORIG','CHANGE']})
>>> df
   DATA  DO   ID    ID2
0  ORIG   3  546  AUSER
1  ORIG   6  107  BUSER
2  ORIG   8  478  CUSER
3  ORIG   4  546  AUSER
4  ORIG   6  478  EUSER

>>> df2
     DATA  DO   ID    ID2
0  CHANGE   6  107  BUSER
1  CHANGE   3  546  AUSER
2  CHANGE   2  123  DUSER
3    ORIG   4  546  AUSER
4  CHANGE   3  123  FUSER

#Compare Dataframes
merged = df2.merge(df, indicator=True, how='outer')

#Split the merged comparison into:
# - original records that will be updated or deleted 
# - new records that will be inserted or update the original record.
df_original = merged.loc[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop(columns=['_merge']).copy()
df_new = merged.loc[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns=['_merge']).copy()

#Create another merge to determine if the new records will either be updates or inserts
check = pd.merge(df_new,df_original, how='left', left_on=['ID','ID2','DO'], right_on = ['ID','ID2','DO'], indicator=True)
in_temp  = check[['ID','ID2','DO']].loc[check['_merge']=='left_only']
upd_temp = check[['ID','ID2','DO']].loc[check['_merge']=='both']

#Create dataframes for each Transaction:
# - removals: Remove records based on provided key values
# - updates:  Update entire record based on key values
# - inserts:  Insert entire record
removals = pd.concat([df_original[['ID','ID2','DO']],df_new[['ID','ID2','DO']],df_new[['ID','ID2','DO']]]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
updates  = df2.loc[(df2['ID'].isin(upd_temp['ID']))&(df2['ID2'].isin(upd_temp['ID2']))&(df2['DO'].isin(upd_temp['DO']))].copy()
inserts  = df2.loc[(df2['ID'].isin(in_temp['ID']))&(df2['ID2'].isin(in_temp['ID2']))&(df2['DO'].isin(in_temp['DO']))].copy()
```

results:

```
>>> removals
    ID    ID2  DO
6  478  CUSER   8
8  478  EUSER   6

>>> updates
     DATA  DO   ID    ID2
0  CHANGE   6  107  BUSER
1  CHANGE   3  546  AUSER

>>> inserts
     DATA  DO   ID    ID2
2  CHANGE   2  123  DUSER
4  CHANGE   3  123  FUSER
```

To restate the questions. Will this logic consistently and correctly identify the differences between two dataframes with specified key columns? Is there a more efficient or pythonic approach to this?

**Updated Sample Data with more records and the corresponding results.**

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
#Sample Data:
df  = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[546,107,478,546], 'ID2':['AUSER','BUSER','CUSER','AUSER'], 'DO':[3,6,8,4], 'DATA':['ORIG','ORIG','ORIG','ORIG']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[107,546,123,546], 'ID2':['BUSER','AUSER','DUSER','AUSER'], 'DO':[6,3,2,4], 'DATA':['CHANGE','CHANGE','CHANGE','ORIG']})
```

For changed:

```
#Concat both df and df2 together, and whenever there is two of the same, drop them both
df3 =  pd.concat([df, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep = False)

#Whenever the size of this following group by is 2 or more there was a change.
#Change
df3 = df3.groupby(['ID', 'ID2', 'DO'])['DATA']\
         .size()\
         .reset_index()\
         .query('DATA == 2')

df3.loc[:, 'DATA'] = 'CHANGE'

     ID  ID2    DO    DATA
0   107 BUSER    6   CHANGE
3   546 AUSER    3   CHANGE
```

For Inserts:

```
#We can compare the ID comlumn for df and df2 and see whats new in df2

#Inserts
df2[(np.logical_not(df2['ID'].isin(df['ID'])))&
    (np.logical_not(df2['ID2'].isin(df['ID2'])))&
    (np.logical_not(df2['DO'].isin(df['DO'])))]

     ID  ID2    DO   DATA
2   123 DUSER   2   CHANGE
```

For Removals:

```
#Similar logic as above but flipped.

#Removals
df[(np.logical_not(df2['ID'].isin(df['ID'])))&
   (np.logical_not(df2['ID2'].isin(df['ID2'])))&
   (np.logical_not(df2['DO'].isin(df['DO'])))]

     ID  ID2    DO  DATA
2   478 CUSER   8   ORIG
```

**EDIT**

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[546,107,478,546,478], 'ID2':['AUSER','BUSER','CUSER','AUSER','EUSER'], 'DO':[3,6,8,4,6], 'DATA':['ORIG','ORIG','ORIG','ORIG','ORIG']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[107,546,123,546,123], 'ID2':['BUSER','AUSER','DUSER','AUSER','FUSER'], 'DO':[6,3,2,4,3], 'DATA':['CHANGE','CHANGE','CHANGE','ORIG','CHANGE']})
```

New dataframes. For changed we will do it the exact same way:

```
df3 =  pd.concat([df, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep = False)

#Change
Change = df3.groupby(['ID', 'ID2', 'DO'])['DATA']\
         .size()\
         .reset_index()\
         .query('DATA == 2')

Change.loc[:, 'DATA'] = 'CHANGE'

    ID   ID2    DO   DATA
0   107 BUSER   6   CHANGE
5   546 AUSER   3   CHANGE
```

For inserts/ removals we will do the same groupby as above, except query for the ones that only appear once. Then we will follow up with an inner join with both df and df2 to see what has been added/removed.

```
InsertRemove = df3.groupby(['ID', 'ID2', 'DO'])['DATA']\
                  .size()\
                  .reset_index()\
                  .query('DATA == 1')

#Inserts
Inserts = InsertRemove.merge(df2, how = 'inner',  left_on= ['ID', 'ID2', 'DO'], right_on = ['ID', 'ID2', 'DO'])\
                      .drop('DATA_x', axis = 1)\
                      .rename({'DATA_y':'DATA'}, axis = 1)

     ID  ID2    DO   DATA
0   123 DUSER   2   CHANGE
1   123 FUSER   3   CHANGE

#Removals
Remove  = InsertRemove.merge(df, how = 'inner',  left_on= ['ID', 'ID2', 'DO'], right_on = ['ID', 'ID2', 'DO'])\
                      .drop('DATA_x', axis = 1)\
                      .rename({'DATA_y':'DATA'}, axis = 1)

     ID  ID2    DO  DATA
0   478 CUSER   8   ORIG
1   478 EUSER   6   ORIG
```

Comment: For inserts and removals, it can not pay attention to just the 'ID' column as that column by itself is not actually unique. It may have duplicates. These much check all three of the indicated columns.

For updates/changes can you update your suggestion in a way that preserves the value in the 'DATA' column?

Comment: @DrewAschenbrener, thats fine! We can also look at the other two columns. Ill edit my post. Also you just want the data column to say what is says in df2?

Comment: I'm sorry Ben, I had to replace my last comment. The inserts and removals section you have, is now not allowing duplicates of the same value in any of those three columns. I don't think I provided a big enough data set at the beginning. I'm going to update my original post for more clarity.

Comment: @DrewAschenbrener, No problem! Ill update my solution. We will have to take a different approach for Inserts and Removals (Actually its probably a better way to begin with).

Comment: I did a bit of research, and I may be wrong, but I think the .isin() function will cause issues with grouped key columns. It searches entire columns independently even when you group the logic. `df2[np.logical_not(df2[['ID','DO','ID2']].isin(df[['ID','DO','ID2']]))]`

Comment: That's correct. Instead of even doing it that way I went about it in a different fashion using inner joins with whatever wasnt duplicated in df3. This is a lot better in your case.